# Why my webpack named chunk not working?

Tags: webpack

I am trying to use webpack code splitting with named chunk by following [this tutorial](http://jonathancreamer.com/advanced-webpack-part-2-code-splitting/). Code splitting works, but when I try to name the split chunk, it doesn't work. 
Here is my code for naming the split chunk:

```
$('.load_link').on('click', function() {

    require.ensure(['./extra'], function(require) {
        require('./extra');

    }, 'extra_bundle');
    // the name doesn't work, but splitting works
});
```

Here is my webpack config:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: ['webpack/hot/dev-server','./src/app.js'],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({template: './src/index.html'})
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" }
        ]
    }
};
```

The named chunk doesn't work is because I can see the split chunk is still using the generic name:

[image]

I expect the 1.bundle.js to be "extra_bundle.js", but it is not.
How to make the chunk name works?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the chunk name to be visible in the filename, you need to set the `chunkFilename` in your output settings and use the `[name]` token. An example:

```
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.[hash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].[hash].[chunkhash].chunk.js',
  },
```

You don't have to use all of them of course, `[name].js` is a perfectly valid chunkFilename too, but feel free to go wild!

Comment: This does not actually change anything, (in webpack 4) ..

Answer (score 0):

to address the OP's issue more specifically;

to get the proper chunk name, pass it as the *fourth* argument, like so:

```js
require.ensure(['./extra'], function(require) {
    require('./extra');
}, function (error) {
    console.error('mayday! mayday!', error);
}, 'extra_bundle');
```

from the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-async/#require-ensure-):

> #### require.ensure()
>
> The syntax is as follows:
>
> ```
> require.ensure(
>     dependencies: String[],
>     callback: function(require),
>     errorCallback: function(error),
>     chunkName: String
> )
> ```